CMD no reconoce Node.js y npm
CMD no reconoce Node.js y npm, sin embargo powershell si, el problema surgió desde que reinstalé node para poder tener una versión más reciente.

¿Como podría hacer que CMD reconozca los comandos de npm y Node.js?

¿adonde está ubicado node.exe?  tal vez no sea visible en %path%.

En PowerShell puedes ejecutar Node.js de forma nativa sin necesidad de configuraciones adicionales, pero para usarlo en el símbolo del sistema debes asegurarte de que la ruta del ejecutable de Node.js agregada en la variable de entorno PATH.
